# Count rows in a dynamically created table

Tags: jquery

I am adding rows to a table on the click of a button.

What I would like to do is when the user clicks a button, Check the table that is dynamically generated number of rows. If the number of rows in that table is "0" - blank, Show a modal popup.

Otherwise don't show the modal.

My current jQuery just keeps returning 0 for num_rows.

```
$('.odds-btn').click(function()
    {
        var rowCount = $('#betting_table tr').length;

        var bet_type = $(this).attr('data-bet-type');
        var bet_line = $(this).attr('data-bet-line');

        if(bet_line == undefined)
        {
            bet_line = '0';
        }

        var game_id = $(this).attr('data-game-id');
        var bet_id = $(this).attr('data-offer-type-id');
        var team = $(this).attr('data-team-name');
        var odds = $(this).attr('data-odds-fractional');

        var url = "/index/build_betslip/" + bet_type + "/" + game_id + "/" + bet_id + "/" + team + "/" + odds + "/" + bet_line;

        $.ajax({
            type:   "GET",
            url: url,
            success:function()
            {
                alert(rowCount);

                if(rowCount == 0)
                {
                    // Add To The Bet Slip....
                    $('.slip-modal').modal('show');
                }

            }
        })

    })
```

The PHP Functions I am using are :

```
public function build_betslip()
    {
        // Get Bet Type (1, 2, X, bttsyes, bttsno, under, over)
        $bet_type = $this->uri->segment(3);

        // Get Game ID
        $game_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        // Get Bet ID (e.g 1X2 = WLD)
        $bet_id = $this->uri->segment(5);

        // Get Team Name
        $teamname = $this->uri->segment(6);

        // Get Odds
        $odds1 = $this->uri->segment(7);
        $odds2 = $this->uri->segment(8);

        // Get Bet Line (1.5 / 2.5 - For Under / Over Market)
        $bet_line = $this->uri->segment(9);

        $odds = $odds1;
        $odds .= "/";
        $odds .= $odds2;

        // Build An array titled Bet
        $bet = array(
            '0' => array(
                'bet_type'  =>  $bet_type,
                'game_id'   =>  $game_id,
                'bet_id'    =>  $bet_id,
                'team'      =>  urldecode($teamname),
                'odds'      =>  $odds,
                'line'      =>  $bet_line
            )
        );

        $betslip = $this->session->userdata('betslip');

        // Create The Betslip For The First Time...
        if(empty($betslip))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('betslip', $bet);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add To The Betslip Array...
            $betslip[] = array(
                'bet_type'  =>  $bet_type,
                'game_id'   =>  $game_id,
                'bet_id'    =>  $bet_id,
                'team'      =>  urldecode($teamname),
                'odds'      =>  $odds,
                'line'      =>  $bet_line
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('betslip', $betslip);
        }

    }

    /*
     * This Function Gets
     * The Current Users' Bet Slip
     * And builds a table based on it and returns as
     * Suitable data
     */

    public function get_betslip()
    {
        $betslip = $this->session->userdata('betslip');

        if(empty($betslip))
        {
            echo "<p>Bet slip is currently empty</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            // Return The Table...
            echo "<table class='table' id='betting_table'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
                    echo "<th>Your Selection</th>";
                    echo "<th>Odds</th>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                    foreach($betslip as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<tr class="table-row-' . $key .'">';
                        echo "<td><a class='bet-cross' data-row='$key' href='#'>x</a></td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo $value['team'];
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo $value['odds'];
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";

            echo "<a class='clear-slip'  href='".base_url('betslip/clear')."'>Clear Slip</a>";

            echo "<a class='site-btn compare' href='".base_url('betslip')."'></a>";
        }


    }
```

Example response from AJAX code :

```
<table class='table' id='betting_table'><thead><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Your Selection</th><th>Odds</th></thead><tbody><tr class="table-row-0"><td><a class='bet-cross' data-row='0' href='#'>x</a></td><td>Wigan Athletic VS Charlton Athletic &#40;Draw&#41;</td><td>5/2</td></tr><tr class="table-row-1"><td><a class='bet-cross' data-row='1' href='#'>x</a></td><td>Atalanta</td><td>21/1</td></tr></tbody></table><a class='clear-slip'  href='http://local.oddssweeper/betslip/clear'>Clear Slip</a><a class='site-btn compare' href='http://local.oddssweeper/betslip'></a>
```

By default, The table is empty.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you are adding rows to your table ?

Comment: Adding rows to a table, then counting the number of rows that are added to see if there is at least one seems a bit convoluted. Can't you just set a flag whenever you add a row?

Comment: Looks like you need to add some code in your success handler to add the data you are getting back from your Ajax request to the table

Comment: @paul That seems a good idea. Can you count the number of times a button has been clicked?

Comment: try `$('#betting_table', 'tr').length;`

Comment: @StuBlackett yes. But if a button click calls a function, you would probably want to count the number of times that the function was called.

Comment: @Brewal I have added relevant PHP code

Comment: @StuBlackett But you need to add its output in the success callback *clientside*

Comment: Cheers @paul I've gone with your solution! I then check the value if its "1" show the modal. Otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first verify that is there any row `<tr>` is present in table,

ex:

```
var rowCount = $('#betting_table').find('tr').length;
```

above code find out that is row present in table or not .

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are returning the table from ajax so in order to make the counter work you need to move `var rowCount = $('#betting_table tr').length;` in ajax success callback and run selection on the `response`, then `jQuery` will find the table and give you the count

```
var rowCount = 0;
....

$.ajax({
        type:   "GET",
        url: url,
        success:function(resp)
        {
            //try checking in response 
            rowCount = $(resp).find('#betting_table tr').length;

            alert(rowCount);

            if(rowCount == 0)
            {
                // Add To The Bet Slip....
                $('.slip-modal').modal('show');
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi @Saqueib this keeps returning "0" each time.